# Antonyms yet homophones

Tags: homophony, antonymy

In Japanese, 私立 means 'private' and 市立 means 'public, city-owned', both are pronounced *shiritsu*. Is such a troublesome phenomenon common? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 3):

see [autoantonym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autoantonym). They might have a category for those, too.

Comment: There is a category https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Contranyms_by_language and also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_contranyms